# How to overcome Maximum size of callout request or response in an external callout

Tags: apex, callout

Hi All I have a requirement were external webservice should handle more than 3MB of data.   I am trying to send document/files to external system using callout.  Is there any alternative way such as sharing a url for document/files? Can I use any other API apart from SOAP to achieve this?  If use the callout in Batch  apex/Future class can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've faced the same issue time ago. In my case the files where stored as attachments.

I must warn you that **sending the complete file body is a bad idea**. You will not only face the size limit, also the time limit. Avoid that idea

My workaround to overcame that limit was to send the **URL** to get the attachment body by REST. Then the external service get the file content.

Sample:

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Attachment/001D000000INjVe/body -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

The rest of the file metadata (name, etc) is send with the url.

More information about this [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

Answer (score 0):

You could break the file up into separate pieces and send the pieces. I believe the callout limit is 10 callouts per execution, so you could send about 30MB of data.

You could do something like this:

```
Blob blob = yourFile;
String file = blob.toString();
List<String> chunks = magicallySplitStringInto3mbChunks(file);
if(chunks.size() < 10){
    Integer chunkNum = 0;
    for(String chunk: chunks){
        Map<Integer, String> postData = new Map<Integer,String>();
        postData.put(chunkNum, chunk);
        String jsons = JSON.serialize(postData);
        postChunk(jsons);
        chunkNum ++;
   }
}
```